# How to get sum of entries having cats, subcats and 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

`table1`:

```
catid   level   entries
   57       1         0
   58       2         5
   59       2         4
   84       1         0
```

`table2`:

```
   id  parent      type
   58      57       cat
   59      57       cat
```

I want to get the `SUM` of subcategory entries and add them to the parent category entries field. In first table the result should be 9 where `catid` is `57`.

How can I do that?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: Unlike SQL Server and Oracle (and probably a few more RDBMS's), MySQL does not support this in a single query unless the max number of levels is fixed. Is the depth arbitrary or fixed to a (reasonably small) max?

Comment: here is a cat, subcat and 2 tables: http://www.geekologie.com/2010/02/28/cat-table-1.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select a.*, b.sum_subcat from table1 a
inner join 
(
  SELECT t2.parent, sum(entries) sum_subcat
  FROM table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 
  on t1.catid = t2.id 
  group by t2.parent
)b on a.catid = b.parent
where a.catid = 57;
```

[SQL DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf975/8)